# rails validation: :allow_nil and :inclusion both needed at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, inclusion

Usually the field 'kind' should be allowed blank.
but if it is not blank, the value should included in ['a', 'b']

```rb
validates_inclusion_of :kind, :in => ['a', 'b'], :allow_nil => true
```

The code does not work?

Comment: you tell us, did it work in your tests?

Comment: it does not work in my rspec?

Answer (score 53):

In Rails 5 you can use `allow_blank: true` outside or inside inclusion block:

```
validates :kind, inclusion: { in: ['a', 'b'], allow_blank: true }
```

or

```
validates :kind, inclusion: { in: ['a', 'b'] }, allow_blank: true
```

tip: you can use `in: %w(a b)` for text values

Comment: Rails 5.2: `allow_blank` and `allow_nil` both work independently. You'll need to restart the web server if you're changing this code in your model.rb.

Comment: Rails 5.2: `allow_nil` does _not_ work either inside or outside the hash. `allow_blank` _does_ work.

Comment: Note, the difference in placement affects the error message(s) generated when the the attribute fails validation.

Answer (score 50):

This syntax will perform inclusion validation while allowing nils:

```
validates :kind, :inclusion => { :in => ['a', 'b'] }, :allow_nil => true
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think allow_nil might need to be inside of the inclusion hash

Comment: The syntax is correct for Rails 3.2 (tested), I don't know if your suggestion might be valid for another version?

Comment: Perhaps. It looks wrong to me because it is really an exception to the inclusion requirement, which by itself would fail. If it works it works!

Comment: It's an exception to any validation, if the value is blank, no further validation is performed.

Answer (score 9):

check also :allow_blank => true

Comment: `allow_nil: true` did not work in a Rails 4 app I was working on. I can confirm that this does work in Rails 4.

Comment: confirming `allow_nil: true` does NOT work in rails 5... this does work in Rails 5.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to achieve this in Rails 5 in a `belongs_to` association, consider that the default behaviour requires the value to exist.

To opt out from this behaviour you must specify the `optional` flag:

```
belongs_to :foo, optional: true 

validates :foo, inclusion: { in: ['foo', 'bar'], allow_blank: true }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 5.x you need, in addition to the following line, to call a `before_validation` method:

```
validates_inclusion_of :kind, :in => ['a', 'b'], :allow_nil => true
```

The `before_validation` is needed to convert the submitted blank value to `nil`, otherwise `''` is not considered `nil`, like this:

```
  before_validation(on: [:create, :update]) do
    self.kind = nil if self.kind == ''
  end
```

For database disk space usage it is of course better to store `nil`'s than storing empty values as empty strings.